# How to get UIElement out of templated data in ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Okay, i feel slightly dumb for askin this but, I have a listview with a templated class MyClass or whatever, whenever i "myListView.Add(new MyClass())" the winrt platform adds a new UIElement there and binds the proper properties into their proper uielements properly, now, I want to be able to iterate through these logical items (myListView.Items or myListView.SelectedItems) and get their corresponding UIElement for animation, is that possible?

like for example

```
class PhoneBookEntry {
    public String Name { get;set }
    public String Phone { get;set }
    public PhoneBookEntry(String name, String phone) {
        Name = name; Phone = phone;
    }
};

myListView.Add(new PhoneBookEntry("Schwarzeneger", "123412341234");
myListView.Add(new PhoneBookEntry("Stallone", "432143214321");
myListView.Add(new PhoneBookEntry("Statham", "567856785678");
myListView.Add(new PhoneBookEntry("Norris", "666666666666");
```

And in XAML (just an example so i can explain what I mean)

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}"/>
         </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

So, my point and objective here is to

```
foreach(PhoneBookEntry pbe in myListView.Items) // or SelectedItems 
{
    UIElement el; // How can I get the UIElement associated to this PhoneBookEntry pbe?
    if(el.Projection == null)
        el.Projection = new PlaneProjection;
    PlaneProjection pp = el.Projection as PlaneProjection;
    // Animation code goes here.
    if(myListView.SelectedItems.Contains(pbe)
        //something for selected
    else
        //something for not selected
}
```

I just need a way to get an UIElement which is being used to represent this logical data class PhoneBookEntry in the templated listview.
Also, this necessity comes with a very big problem I'm having where, selected items doesn't differ visually on Windows Phone -_- any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the [ListView.ContainerFromItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromitem(v=win.10).aspx) or ListView.ContainerFromIndex methods which will return the container UI element for a given item in the list view (of course, only if the container is generated)

Comment: I have tested and studied with this solution and it directly responds to the basic question, ty.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I may look like a fool answering my own question but i've figured a way out.

First things first: ListViews only create UIElements for determinate items in the list (the ones cached and the ones being shown). So if you do add 2000 items to myListView.Items, the effective ammount of UIElements representing these items will be 56 or close number.
Because, the ItemListView simulates the UIElements even if they're not there, just to give size and position to the scrollbar (hence why scrolling down on very large lists cause some lag, WinRT is unloading UIElements and loading new ones)

From that, I figured out I could simply iterate through the current list of loaded UIElements through

```
// For each of the cached elements
foreach(LIstViewItem lvi in myListView.ItemsPanelRoot.Children) 
{
    // Inside here I can get the base object used to fill the data template using:
    PhoneBookEntry pbe = lvi.Content as PhoneBookEntry;
    if(pbe.Name == "Norris")
        BeAfraid();
    // Or check if this ListViewItem is or not selected:
    bool isLviSelected = lvi.IsSelected;
    // Or, like I wanted to, get an UIElement to animate projection
    UIElement el = lvi as UIElement;
    if(el.Projection == null)
        el.Projection = new PlaneProjection();
    PlaneProjection pp = el.Projection as PlaneProjection;
    // Now I can use pp to rotate, move and whatever with this UIElement.
}
```

So, this is it. Right beneath my nose...

Comment: The ListView class does not have an ItemsPanelRoot property :-/

Comment: Then there is something quite wrong there, this question regarded WinRT 8.1 and uses the object type Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView as specified in this document:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview